# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{- \sqrt n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to study the character of this series 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{- \sqrt n}$$
and I tried with the condensation criterion of Caughy:

(1) $2^{- \sqrt n}>0, \forall n \ge 0$

(2) $2^{- \sqrt {n+1}} \le 2^{- \sqrt n}$

(3) $2^{- \sqrt n} \rightarrow 0 $ for  $n \rightarrow + \infty$

then we can use the condensation criterion of Caughy and say that
our serie converges $\leftrightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n 2^{- \sqrt {2^n}}$
converges.

With the root criterion:
$\sqrt [n]{2^n 2^{- \sqrt {2^n}}}=2 \star 2^{- \frac{\sqrt{2^n}}{n}}=2 \star  2^{- \sqrt {\frac{{2^n}}{n^2}}} \sim 2*0=0<1 $ and the given series converges.
In particular,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} {- \sqrt {\frac{{2^n}}{n^2}}} = -\infty$
because the exponential function grows quicker than any power of n.
Is it right?

Comment: It's Cauchy, not Caughy, and in point $(2)$ you have the inequality sign backwards, but otherwise, it looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using $2^x=(1+1)^x\geq 1+x$ for any $x\geq 0$ we have
$$ 2^{\sqrt{n}}= \left(2^{\sqrt{n}/4}\right)^4 \geq \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4}\right)^4\geq 1+\frac{n^2}{256} $$
so your series is convergent. Yet another way is to exploit the fact that $2^{-\sqrt{x}}$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$, so
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} 2^{-\sqrt{n}} \leq 1+\int_{0}^{+\infty}2^{-\sqrt{x}}\,dx=1+\frac{2}{\log^2 2}.$$

Comment: Just to see if I understood, your second line proves convergence because if we take reciprocals, we obtain 

$$ 2^{- \sqrt{n} } \leq \dfrac{1}{1+ n^2/256} \leq \dfrac{256}{n^2} $$ 

and since $\sum \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ converges, then our original series converges by comparison test. Is this correct?